# I'm getting positional argument in Django rest framework APIView class empty. Why? And how to pass value into it?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm playing with DRF just for fun and I'm trying to get single record by its ID.

Here is my setup:

Django version 2.1.4

DjangoRestFramework 3.9.0

**models.py**

```
class BoardModel(models.Model):
    board_title = models.CharField(
        ...
    )
    board_c_time = models.DateTimeField(
        ...
    )
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^get_board(?P<pk>\d*)$', views.GetBoard.as_view(), name="get-board"),
]
```

**serializers.py**

```
class GetBoardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
"""Board serializer."""

class Meta:
    model = BoardModel
    fields = ("id", "board_title", "board_c_time")
```

**views.py**

```
class GetBoard(APIView):
"""Get single board."""

def get_object(self, pk):
    """Search for the object."""
    try:
        return models.BoardModel.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except models.BoardModel.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
    """GET method."""
    pk = int(request.query_params.get('pk'))
    obj = self.get_object(pk)
    serializer = GetBoardSerializer(obj)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Sending GET request to `my_url.com/api/get_board?pk=123`.

Positional argument 'pk' in the `get` method of `GetBoard` class should take the value from the `pk` parameter in url (eg  `pk='123'`) however it returns an empty string.

Because of that I had to access it through `request.query_params.get('pk')` but it looks weird to me.

Did I miss something?

How to get value from the URL parameter into positional argument in the get method mentioned above?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to send the parameter as a query param which are the params identified in a url after the `?` character, then you'll need to access them via `request.query_params`. If you want to pass it through the url, then you should adjust your urls.py to:

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^get_board/(?P<pk>\d*)$', views.GetBoard.as_view(), name="get-board"),
]
```

Then your url should be: `my_url.com/api/get_board/123`

Comment: Thank you @schillingt , it makes sense after you explained it.